# Get notified when an Element inside a Map changes by Two-Way-Databinding

Tags: data-binding, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

So if I bind two simple Variables with two-way-databinding in polymer, they get updated automatically.

But I noticed Maps and Lists behave differently. Changing an Element inside of a Map or List does not update the bound variables, only using the = Operator or notifyPropertyChange triggers the update.

My problem is I have two Elements E1 and E2. E1 is the Parent of E2.

```
// E1.dart
class E1 extends PolymerElement {
  @observable List<Map> data;

  dataChanged() => print(data.toString());
}

//E1.html
<...>
   <template repeat="{{map in data}}">
      <E2 value="{{map[identifier]}}"></E2>
   </template>
</...>
```

So if a value inside of E2 changes and I manually print the data, the value also did change. But the dataChanged() function never gets called. I want to call notifyPropertyChange(#data,x,y) on data, when a value inside changes. Is there a way to get a notification on a change inside the List?

My List looks like this:

```
[
  { identifier : {x1 : y1}},
  { identifier : {x2 : y2}},
  { identifier : {x3 : y3}},
  { identifier : {x4 : y4}} 
]
```

The change I want to get notified about is x and y, and if a new Element is added. identifier is always the same btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ObservableList or ObservableMap instead of a regular List or Map. You can also create those automatically by wrapping an existing List or Map in a call to toObservable. For example:

```
@observable ObservableList<Map> data = toObservable([1, 2, 3]);
```

These types/functions are exported by polymer, so you shouldn't need to add any imports.

Comment: When adding a new Element into the List i get notified about that, which is nice. Sadly I still get no notification about a change inside my List. I'll update my post and show how my list looks like